# python import csv lists

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, import

I want to import a CSV into multiple dictionaries in python

```
queryInclude,yahoo,value1
queryInclude,yahoo,value2
queryInclude,yahoo,value3
queryExclude,yahoo,value4
queryExclude,yahoo,value5
queryInclude,google,value6
queryExclude,google,value7
```

My ideal result would have row[0]=dictionary, row[1]=key, and row[2]=value or list of values

```
queryInclude = {
        "yahoo": ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
        "google": ["value6"] }
queryExclude = {
        "yahoo": ["value4", "value5"],
        "google": ["value7"] }
```

Here's my code:

```
import csv
queryList=[]
queryDict={}
with open('dictionary.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        queryDict[row[1]] = queryList.append(row[2])
        print queryDict

{'yahoo': None}
{'yahoo': None}
{'yahoo': None}
{'yahoo': None}
{'yahoo': None}
{'google': None, 'yahoo': None}
{'google': None, 'yahoo': None}
```

I have the flexibility to change the CSV format if needed.  My ideal result posted above is what I already had hard-coded into my app.  I'm trying to make it easier to add more values down the road.  I've spent many hours researching this and will continue to update if I make any more progress.  My thought process looks like this... not sure how close I am to understanding how to structure my loops and combine like values while iterating through the CSV rows...

```
for row in reader:
    where row[0] = queryInclude:
        create a dictionary combining keys into a list of values
    where row[0] = queryExclude:
        create a dictionary combining keys into a list of values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this helping?

```
import StringIO
import csv

csvfile = StringIO.StringIO("""queryInclude,yahoo,value1
queryInclude,yahoo,value2
queryInclude,yahoo,value3
queryExclude,yahoo,value4
queryExclude,yahoo,value5
queryInclude,google,value6
queryExclude,google,value7""")

reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

dict1={}
for row in reader:
    key1, provider, value1 = row
    if not dict1.has_key(key1):
        dict1[key1] = {}
    if not dict1[key1].has_key(provider):
        dict1[key1][provider] = []
    dict1[key1][provider].append(value1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `defaultdict` prevents having to account for the first element added to a dictionary.  It declares the default type when the key is not present and must be a callable that creates the default object:

```
#! python3
import csv
from io import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

data = StringIO('''\
queryInclude,yahoo,value1
queryInclude,yahoo,value2
queryInclude,yahoo,value3
queryExclude,yahoo,value4
queryExclude,yahoo,value5
queryInclude,google,value6
queryExclude,google,value7
''')

D = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for d,k,v in csv.reader(data):
    D[d][k].append(v)
pprint(D)
```

Output:

```
{'queryExclude': {'google': ['value7'],
                  'yahoo': ['value4', 'value5']},
 'queryInclude': {'google': ['value6'],
                  'yahoo': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}}
```

Comment: That is a clean implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the python3 example.  Works great!